# Displaying other language characters in PyQt

Tags: python, unicode, pyqt, pyqt4

Is there a way to display other language characters in PyQt4?
and if there is, what's the approach/direction that I should take?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Um, languages other than what?

Comment: @chryss: other than his, of course :) ok, I'm joking, he probably meant "non-ASCII" characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qt uses Unicode and should be able to display (Unicode) text in any language you have a suitable font for.  For example, Roberto Alesina's simple "Hello World" program on the [PyQt Wiki](http://diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/HelloWorld) -- which I transcribe for readability (and w/o the comments for brevity) since it's pretty unreadable in the wiki -- should let you use as the button's text any such Unicode text (so I've taken the liberty of translating it so it uses an accented letter;-)...:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# (or w/ever other coding you use for unicode literals;-)
import qt, sys
a=qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
w=qt.QPushButton(u"Olá Mundo", None)
w.show()
a.exec_loop()
```