# Accents with PyQt5

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, pyqt

I'm trying to make a program with a QMainWindow and a **QMenuBar**. But when I try to add an action with text with **accent**, that show a **weird** thing. For example, for "`Préférences` : "`PrÃ©fÃ©rences`".

Code (not entire) :

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def setupUi(self):
        self.menubar = self.menuBar()
        menu = self.menubar.addMenu("Fichier")
        act = QAction()
        act.setText("Préférences")

        self.show()
win = MainWindow()
win.setupUi()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: *I'm trying to make a program…* - please share a [mcve].

Comment: what is the output of `print(menu.font().family())`?

Comment: I added a minimal reproductible example, thanks ! And ```print(menu.font().family())``` give : ```MS Shell Dlg 2```. Note that even in the title of the window, I have this problem (I just noticed)

Comment: Have you looked at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183044/displaying-other-language-characters-in-pyqt

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying other language characters in PyQt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183044/displaying-other-language-characters-in-pyqt)

Comment: Okay ! Thanks, that worked... but how to transfer regular string to unicode string ? I saw that str = unicode now in python, so ?